# RestEasy JAX-RS ApplicationPath returns 404

Tags: java, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy, java-ee-7

I'm converting an app from `Jboss 6.4/Java8 -> JBoss 7.2/Java11` and I'm running into the error where my endpoint annotations seem to be ignored by the app and return error code `404.` You can see in the logs where the web context is registered and where the `web.xml` authenticates the path based on the security constraint, but the request still returns a `404.`

I've updated the EE and REST libraries but to no avail.

The app has 2 `@ApplicationPath` annotations. How are the `JAXRS` annotation different from EAP6 to EAP7?

[image: 404 Error]

**RestApplication**

```
package com.web;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

**AppResource**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/applications")
public class AppResource{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppResource.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getApplications() {
    ...
    }
    ...

}
```

**jboss-deployment-structure**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="WebApp.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/>
            <module name="javaee.api"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.msc"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.server"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Could you try without the `@Path("/")` annotation? It's not necessary, and should do nothing, but may be if confusing `resteasy`

Answer (score 0):

Jaxrs subsystem was missing from my standalone so I needed to add it manually.

**SCR**

```
#JAXRS
if (outcome != success) of /subsystem=jaxrs:read-resource()
    /subsystem=jaxrs:add()
    reload
end-if
```

**standalone**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
```